# Magento 1.9 - How to set PCI Compliance script integrity check for merged js file

Tags: javascript, magento1.9.2.4, pci

I had scan the site with PCI scan. But it is failed and its score is 7.8. Following are the scan results of PCI scan:

**Title:**
Script Src Integrity Check

**Synopsis:**
Report external script resources not using integrity.

**Impact:**
The remote host may be vulnerable to payment entry data exfiltration
due to javascript included from potentially untrusted and unverified third
parties script src. If the host is controlled by a 3rd party, ensure that the 3rd party is PCI DSS compliant.

**Resolution:**
Set script integrity checking on target script or remove target script.

**Data recieved:**
example.com/media/js/90a8720cd608ccab8eaf40398
728caf8.js Attributes : - type : text/javascript - src :

I can generate the integrity hash for single script by running following command:
cat jquery.js | openssl dgst -sha384 -binary | openssl base64 -A

My question is - How I can set the script integrity for the merged file like below:
example.com/media/js/90a8720cd608ccab8eaf40398
728caf8.js

I have merged the JS and CSS files in Magento. I want to set the script integrity for the merged js file.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more?

Comment: I have updated the question. Let me know if you need more details.